# Continuous Fourier transform of a discrete convolution

Tags: calculus, fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

I have some problems in understanding the convolution theorem in the case of a Fourier transform (FT) of a discrete convolution. Suppose I have the discrete convolution
$$
r(x) = \sum_j f(x) g(x-z_j)
$$
where the functions $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ have FT $F(k)$ and $G(k)$ respectively. What would be the FT
$$
R(k) = \int dx  r(x) e^{i k x}
$$

In the case of a continuous convolution I would expect $R(k)=F(k)G(k)$, but according to some numerical tests I made it looks more something like $R(k)\approx\sum_j F(q_j) G(k-q_j)$.

I do not have clear if at some point I need to introduce a discrete FT.